# Picard group of the tensor product $\bar K \otimes_K \bar K$ (product of schemes)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a field. What is the Picard group of the ring $R := \bar K \otimes_K \bar K$?

---

I have seen the question [Picard group of product of spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493005/picard-group-of-product-of-spaces), but it only deals with varieties over an algebraically closed field.

If $K$ is perfect, then $R$ is a direct product of copies of $\bar K$ indexed by the absolute Galois group of $K$. I guess in that case that $\operatorname{Pic}(R)=0$, but I am not sure. Moreover, in general, $R$ may not be reduced.

Comment: The seesaw theorem could help (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81611/picard-groups-of-fiber-products)

Comment: I don’t think the seesaw is the correct viewpoint here. I think a simple limit argument suffices, ie that the Picard group is the colimit of the Picard groups of $\overline{K} \otimes L$ over finite $L/K$, which are all zero by KReiser’s deleted answer.

Comment: Good catch, @Aphelli!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, $\operatorname{Pic} R=0$. This follows from a few facts:

1. If $S=\lim S_i$ is a limit of a directed system of qcqs schemes $S_i$ with affine transition maps, then $\operatorname{Pic} S = \operatorname{colim} \operatorname{Pic} S_i$ ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8W))
2. Every finite-dimensional algebra over a field is a finite direct product of Artinian local rings ([ref 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46654/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-8-3-artinian-iff-finite-k-algebra) + [ref 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3243164/every-artinian-ring-is-isomorphic-to-a-direct-product-of-artinian-local-rings))
3. The Picard group of a finite direct product of rings is the product of the Picard groups of the factors ([ref](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233734/the-picard-group-of-a-product-of-rings))
4. Line bundles over affine schemes correspond to projective modules ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NV))
5. Any projective module over a local ring is free ([ref](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058Z))

By 1, we may reduce to considering the case of $\overline{K}\otimes_K L$ for finite $L/K$, each of which are a finite-dimensional algebra over $\overline{K}$. By 2, such an algebra splits as a finite direct product of Artinian local rings. Then by 3 we can reduce to considering each of the factors. Next, by 4, we're looking to classify all rank one projective modules over each of these local rings, but by 5 they're all free, and so the Picard group vanishes. (Thanks to Aphelli for pointing out part 1.)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. But here $R$ is not finite-dimensional over $K$. I should see what happens for Picard groups of infinite products.

Comment: Oops, my bad - I'll delete this while I fix it

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good. Thanks for all the references, I am going to look at those, and accept the answer once I check everything.